# Could not import 'edit_contact'. The path must be fully qualified

Tags: python, django

So, I'm trying to create a table filled with contacts in Python/Django. When I attempt to run the program, I get the above error message ("ImportError: Could not import 'edit_contact'. The path must be fully qualified.")

Here is the views.py I'm using:

```
from contacts.models import Contact
#, Address, Telephone
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404, render
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from django.template import loader, Context, RequestContext
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    #return HttpResponse("Hey! You can see contacts here!")
    contact_list = Contact.objects.all().order_by('last_name')
    return render_to_response('contacts/index.html', {'contact_list': contact_list},
            RequestContext(request))

def detail(request, contact_id):
    c = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=contact_id);

def new_contact(request):
    print "new_contact"

    #AddressInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Contact,

    if request.method == "POST":
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    contact = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contacts.views.detail', args=(contact.pk,)))
    else:
            form = ContactForm()

    return render_to_response("contacts/form.html",{
            "form": form,
            }, RequestContext(request))

def edit_contact(request, contact_id):
    contact = Contact.objects.get(pk=contact_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
            form = ContactForm(request.POST, instane=contact)
            if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contacts.views.detail', args=(contact.pk,)))
    else:
            form = ContactForm(instance = contact)
    return render_to_response("contacts/form.html", {
            "form": form,
            }, RequestContext(request))
```

This is the urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<contact_id>\d+)/$', 'detail', name='contactdetailsurl'),
    url(r'^new/$',                 'new_contact', name='newcontacturl'),
    url(r'^(?P<contact_id>\d+)/edit/$','edit_contact', name='editcontacturl'),

]
```

And the error is pointing to this line in my site_base.html file:

```
       <li id="tab_first"><a href="
  {% url contacts.views.index %}
  "><i class="icon-book"></i> Contacts</a></li>
```

Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you should use the full path to the view, for example `'contacts.views.edit_contact'` (assuming the app is called `contacts`).

However, using strings in your URL patterns is deprecated in Django 1.8, and not supported in Django 1.10+. You should using callables instead. You are already using the callable `views.index` for your `index` URL pattern.

I would convert the rest of your URL patterns as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<contact_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='contactdetailsurl'),
    url(r'^new/$', views.new_contact, name='newcontacturl'),
    url(r'^(?P<contact_id>\d+)/edit/$', views.edit_contact, name='editcontacturl'),
]
```

Comment: Okay, that suggestion worked to get rid of that error, but now I'm getting an error that says:
Revere for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []. It points to that same line of code in my .html file as the first error did.
do you understand what's going on here, and how to fix it?

Comment: You should use the *name* when you use the URL patterns, in this case  `{% url 'index' %}`.

Comment: One more suggestion to bring your code up to date: use `render` instead of `render_to_response`, e.g. `return render(request, 'contacts/index.html', {'contact_list': contact_list})`.